# How to access a resource from a different module in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Module 'xyz' should wait 10 mins for module 'abc' residing in a diff dir. Here are the details.

**root/x/main.tf**

```
module "abc" {
  ...
}
resource "time_sleep" "wait_10_mins" {
  depends_on = [module.abc[0]]

  create_duration = "10m"
}
```

**root/y/main.tf**

```
module "xyz" {
  .....

  depends_on = how to access resource time_sleep.wait_10_mins here?
  
}
```

Comment: What is the full namespace of resource `time_sleep`? Is it inside the declared module `abc`?

Comment: resource time_sleep is defined in root/x/main.tf, outside of module abc.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be very close:

You'll only need the `[0]` if the abc module is using `count` or `for_each`:

```
  depends_on = [
    module.abc
  ]
```

and

```
  depends_on = [
    time_sleep.wait_10_mins
  ]
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Yes we have module abc has count. What you suggested I tried it didn't work. It says time_sleep not found. So I have to somehow create link from xyz module of root/y/main.tf to abc module of root/x/main.tf

Comment: I think you may have to explain your setup a bit more, then. I'm missing some information, I reckon. What's the full directory structure of the files? Are they each in separate modules being called from some central location?

Comment: Module abc and resource "time_sleep" "wait_10_mins" are defined in root/x/main.tf
And module xyz is defined in root/y/main.tf.